# How Do I Set and Retrieve an Environment Variable with Docker and .NET 7 in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, docker-compose

I created a .NET 7 Web API App and created the Docker configuration files using the command **Docker: Add Docker Files to Workspace**. When prompted, I also add the Docker compose files. I've added environment variables to my `tasks.json` and `docker-compose.debug.yml` .

I then start my application using the generated launch configuration **Docker .NET Launch.**

None of the environment variables are populated when I call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_VARIABLE")` in my `Program.cs`.

Note that they *are* populated when I use **.NET Core Launch** configuration with an `env` object.

How do I properly set and retrieve environment variables when using my docker image + container?

**Code Examples:**

```yaml
# docker-compose.debug.yml
services:
  myservice:
    image: myservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - FOO=foo
    volumes:
      - ~/.vsdbg:/remote_debugger:rw
```

```json
// tasks.json

        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: release",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build: release"
            ],
            "dockerRun": {
                "env": {
                    "foo": "bar"
                }
            },
            "netCore": {
                "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/Kno2.WebSockets.csproj"
            }
        }
```

```cs
// Program.cs

var foo = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO");
Console.Write(foo); // null
```

I tried setting environment variables in any file that would take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0)...

> Environment variable names are **case-sensitive** on non-Windows systems but are not case-sensitive on Windows.

Your Docker platform is no doubt using one of the official Linux images so you need to match the text case...

```json
"dockerRun": {
  "env": {
    "FOO": "bar"
  }
},
```

---

If you've taken the time to create a Docker Compose configuration, you could instead use a [Docker Compose task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference#_docker-compose-task)

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run docker-compose up",
      "type": "docker-compose",
      "dockerCompose": {
        "up": {
          "detached": true,
          "build": true,
          "services": ["myservice"]
        },
        "files": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.yml",
          "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.debug.yml"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you're correct that I'm using a linux image and thanks for going the extra mile and writing up a sample docker-compose task. I assumed that VS Code was using the docker-compose.debug.yml when running the provided debug launch configuration. This makes it clear that the docker-run task is exactly what it says it is and that the developer has to make their own docker-compose task if they intend to use it, or use the ">Docker: Compose Up" command provided by the extension.